# how to set float and non float element vertical align to bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm running this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/53e47bbo/2/) and I want to set the `vertical-align` property to `bottom` for both the float and non-float elements, but it doesn't work :

Here is my html code :

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
div {
    border: 1px solid;
}
.main {
        text-align: center;
}

.main:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
.main > div {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 20%;
}

.left {
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

.right {
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
}

.middle {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're using with a table cells, vertical-align aligns the element with respect to adjacent elements, in particular text.

Read more about vertical alignment here:

http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

What you can do though is give your wrapper a width, height, and set it it to `position: relative`

After that you can use absolute positioning for your divs, set them to `bottom: 0` they will then stick to the bottom of the wrapper.

Here is new CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid;
}
.main {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
      text-align: center;
}

.main:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
        display: block;
}
.main > div {
   width: 20%;
}

.left {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;

}

.right {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
}

.middle {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
   position: absolute;
   transform: translate(-50%, 0%); 
   left: 50%;
   bottom: 0;

}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/wKYvbG)

Comment: thanks but i think the middle div is not in center in your demo.

Comment: it's not a good solution because the with can change, i use `transform: translate(-50%, 0%); left: 50%;` and it works good .. i will wait for other solution without absolute position if there is not other way i will use your answer.

Comment: no it is, its responsive and the container is position relative. Tested on all sizes.

Comment: .... Dude, I helped you figure out how to get your divs on the bottom as YOUR QUESTION asked. Your question was about ALIGNMENT. Ask a more thorough question if there is something else you want. Good job for figuring it out.

Comment: hhhh okey man thanks for help really just update your css in your answer.

Comment: No problem. I updated the pen with your centering solution! Have a nice day!